# With the OData protocol, using filter, how can I write ' instead of %27?

Tags: javascript, url, odata, single-quotes, encodeuricomponent

I want to do a search using the filter parameter of the OData v4 protocol using the contains operator.

In the code I write example?$filter=contains(name,'John').

But in the request this translates to contains(Customers%2C%20%27Victoria%27)

Doing so causes the call to fail.

Is it my mistake because I should make the quotes not convert to %27 or should it also work with the character encoding in %27?

Comment: `%27` and `'` are equivalent, there is no difference between them. Are you really saying that `name` becomes `Customers` and `John` becomes `Victoria`?

Comment: no sorry, my mistake, they are two different examples